# Taking the sum of a list without sum()

Tags: python

I have a list that gets generated when a user inputs a random number they want. I want to add the sum together with out using sum(). How could I do this?

```
xAmount = int(input("How man numbers would you like to input: "))

numList = []

for i in range(0, xAmount):
     numList.append(int(input("Enter a number: ")))



print(numList)
```

From here

Comment: How would you do it by hand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store the sum in a temp variable. Keep adding the input numbers to the temp variable:

```
xAmount = int(input("How man numbers would you like to input: "))

numList = []
numList_sum = 0

for i in range(0, xAmount):
     inputted_number = int(input("Enter a number: "))
     numList_sum += inputted_number
     numList.append(inputted_number)



print(numList)
print(numList_sum)
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a list at all.

```
xAmount = int(input("How man numbers would you like to input: "))
result = 0

for i in range(0, xAmount):
     result = result + int(input("Enter a number: "))

print(result)
```

Comment: I do need a list for my assignment unfortunately... Thanks!

Comment: Then why bother using a temp variable instead of the `sum()` function? @Casey

Answer (score 0):

To sum a list just iterate over the list, adding up the individual values:

```
num_total = 0
for value in numList:
    num_total += value
```

You could also use `reduce` but this might not meet your h/w requirements either:

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import add
num_total = reduce(add, numList, 0)
```

Comment: if you are going to use `reduce`, you should use `operator.add` and don't forget to pass an initial value so it doesn't fail for an empty list. Also, in Python3 `reduce` is now in the `functools` module

Comment: I originally had `operator.add` but decided to remove the import. However, you make a good point with python3... so I can't avoid an import, will add them both in. Whether you need a default value or not depends on the situation.